# Forcing tkinter to 'speak' English

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently developing a cross platform GUI application with Python, and tkinter.

Although I'm German, I want all button labels to be displayed in English. By now it is a strange mix because the messages in `tkMessageBoxes` are in English but `button labels` and `file dialog boxes` are in German.

Is there a way to force Python / tkinter to use English labels only?

Comment: What do you mean the labels are in German? You type English in to your source and it comes out German? Provide example code please.

Comment: Unless you are usuing some sort of translation library, whatever you type is what it's displayed. Please provide your source so we can get a better idea

Comment: What I mean is that Buttons labeled with "Yes" or "No" become "Ja" und "Nein" or file dialog boxes are in German while the program itself is entirely in English. Or, to be more precise, all texts, messages and so on are in English because I wrote them in English.

Comment: Again, provide code! A Tk Button is not the same as using  TkMessageBox.

Comment: Take a look at any standard code to create a standard message box and you have it. When I create a message box using 'messagebox.askyesno', the text within this box is in English because I typed in English words, but the buttons are in German.

Answer (score 1):

On both Linux and Windows, Tcl will use the value of the `LANG` environment variable if set to initialize the locale. So if you set `LANG=en` you will get an English locale. If this is not set, then on Windows it then examines the registry to identify the locale in use and configures from that. You can find the Tcl code doing this in the msgcat.tcl file (search for `registry`).

It will use `LC_ALL`, `LC_MESSAGES` or `LANG` in that order from the environment.

Comment: When I changed `LC_ALL` with `locale.setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8')` inside the script, the buttons remain in French (my default locale). However, the buttons were in English when I did `LANG=en; python myscript.py` in the command line.

Comment: Okay thanks guys. Under these circumstances (coding custom message boxes for standard stuff or diving into Windows' registry hell) I think I can live without having a consistent appearance throughout different countries.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tcl command to change the language of the GUI:

**EDIT:** it works in linux but not in windows, so the only alternative I see to make it work for all platforms is to rewrite custom messageboxes.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox as mbox

root = tk.Tk()

def english():
    root.tk.eval('::msgcat::mclocale en')
    mbox.askyesno('Messagebox', 'Buttons in English')

def german():
    root.tk.eval('::msgcat::mclocale de')
    mbox.askyesno('Messagebox', 'Buttons in German')

tk.Button(root, text='English messagebox', command=english).pack()
tk.Button(root, text='German messagebox', command=german).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the `mbox.askyesno` buttons were both in English. Using Python 3.5.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Works for me but I am using linux

Comment: Tk on windows uses the standard Windows MessageBox common dialog for the yesno and other dialogs. These are provided by the system so will pick up the system locale from Windows. Tk doesn't get to specify the text of the buttons on the messagebox dialogs at all. It just gets to choose buttons from a set of IDs.